# How to make loops play while something else is playing

Tags: loops, roblox

Im making a game right now where one of the characters has a fire ability. i have a loop for the attack but not the fire... How can i make a loop that runs the fire while it still attacks?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include your code so we can help you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the spawn function to run multiple loops at the same time.
For example :

```Lua
task.spawn(function()
    - your code here
end)
```